# Ubuntu 18.04 Budgie: Default file manager

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, budgie

what's Ubuntu 18.04 Budgie's default file manager? I want to know so that I can see if I can add an "access as root" option to right clicking contexts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's *nautilus*.

To find that out, I read the output from

```
apt show ubuntu-budgie-desktop
```

It's in the *Depends* section:

> Depends: alsa-base, alsa-utils, anacron, apport-gtk, bc, budgie-indicator-applet, budgie-lightdm-theme, ca-certificates, curl, dbus-user-session, dmz-cursor-theme, fonts-dejavu-core, fonts-freefont-ttf, foomatic-db-compressed-ppds, gcr, genisoimage, ghostscript-x, gnome-calendar, gnome-control-center, gnome-keyring, gnome-menus, gnome-settings-daemon, gnome-themes-standard, gsettings-desktop-schemas, gstreamer1.0-alsa, gstreamer1.0-packagekit, gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio, gvfs-bin, indicator-application, inputattach, itstool, language-selector-gnome, libcanberra-pulse, libnotify-bin, libsasl2-modules, libu2f-udev, **nautilus**, network-manager, network-manager-gnome, openprinting-ppds, plymouth-theme-ubuntu-budgie-logo, plymouth-theme-ubuntu-budgie-text, plymouth-themes, printer-driver-pnm2ppa, pulseaudio, python3-notify2, rfkill, slick-greeter, software-properties-gtk, spice-vdagent, ssh-askpass-gnome, system-config-printer-common, system-config-printer-udev, tilix, ubuntu-drivers-common, ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk, unzip, update-manager, update-notifier, whoopsie, wireless-tools, wpasupplicant, xdg-user-dirs, xdg-user-dirs-gtk, xkb-data, xorg, xserver-xorg-input-libinput, zenity, zip

Re. the root option, just install the package:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-admin
```

The extension is available for all current Ubuntu releases: Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 16.04, Ubuntu 17.10, and Ubuntu 18.04.